# U-substitution question: How do I get rid of $\cos\theta$ in the integration of $\sin^2(2\theta) d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given $u = \sin\theta$,

I must integrate $\sin^2(2\theta)$.

$$\sin^2(2\theta)    d\theta$$
$$(2\sin\theta \cos\theta)^2  d\theta$$
$$(4\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta)d\theta$$

$$u = \sin\theta$$
$$ du/d\theta = \cos\theta$$
$$d\theta = du/\cos\theta$$

$$4u^2\cos^2\theta * du/\cos\theta$$
$$4u^2\cos\theta * du$$

Now how do I get rid of $\cos\theta$?

Comment: Why do you *want* to use u-substitution on this integral?

Answer (score 2):

Use instead $$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x\implies\sin^22\theta=\frac{1-\cos4\theta}2.$$

We then have
\begin{align}
\int\sin^22\theta\,d\theta&=\int\frac{1-\cos4\theta}2\,d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int1-\cos4\theta\,d\theta\\
&=\frac12\theta-\frac18\sin4\theta+C
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, if you have $u=\sin\theta$, then you have $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-u^2}$ (try drawing a right triangle to see how this is derived).

Then, you will have
\begin{align}
\int\sin^22\theta\,d\theta&=4\int\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=4\int u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du,
\end{align}
which looks to be a tad bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-u^2}$ but that may again require you to go for trigonometric substitution. So it is better to integrate $\sin^2(2\theta)$ as -

$\int \sin^2(2\theta) d \theta = \frac{1}{2} \int 2\sin^2(2\theta) d \theta = \frac{1}{2} \int (1 - \cos 4\theta ) d \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left(\theta - \frac{1}{4}\sin 4\theta \right) + C$

To write your answer in terms of $u$, you can now expand $\sin 4 \theta$. Also note,
$\theta = \arcsin u$.

Comment: My question has told me to use $u = sinx$, so I suppose they'd cut marks if I use another u. Yet I'm a bit unsure how to simplify $4u^2 \sqrt {1-u^2} du$ now...

Comment: @Alpha you are not using another u. $u = sin x$ means $x = arcsin u$. Once you integrate, you will get an x term.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  To integrate $\sin^2 2x$, use $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2 x$.  Thus $\sin^22x=\dfrac{1-\cos4x}2$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, $\cos\theta = \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{1-u^2}$

Then you have to solve, $\int4u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}du$ which is a bit-lengthy.

Instead, you have, $\sin^2(2\theta)=\dfrac{1-\cos(4\theta)}{2}$, and you can easily compute the integral.